# How to disable smart indent in Eclipse for Java code?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I type `class Bar {` + Enter, Eclipse 3.5.2 indents the next line, like this (`_` is the cursor/caret):

```
// Eclipse 3.5.2 does this for Java code by default.
// I don't want this (smart indentation).
class Foo {
  class Bar {
    _
```

How do I disable this so-called smart indentation (for Java code), and revert it back to normal auto-indentation, like this:

```
// I want this (automatic indentation).
class Foo {
  class Bar {
  _
```

Without auto indent, it would look like this:

```
// I don't want this (no indentation)
class Foo {
  class Bar {
_
```

I can work much more efficiently when I am allowed to manage the indentation, without relying on the possible smartness of the editor. I'm not interested in changing my customs how I edit code, I'm interested in getting rid of the smart indentation feature of Eclipse, and enabling automatic indentation.

I've tried various options in *Window / Preferences*, but I haven't found any of them which would solve the problem illustrated above.

Comment: I would claim that not concerning yourself with the indentation of your code makes you more productive. Switch on "format all lines on save", concentrate on writing your code, and let the editor take care of the indentation.

Comment: @JesperE: Thank you for your advice, I'll consider it, but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: The point is that I am challenging the premises of your question. You are *not* working more efficiently when you spend this amount of time making sure that your code layout is correct. This is like fiddling around with typefaces in Word when you really should be focusing on the *text*. Start focusing on the code itself, or you will not be productive at all.

Comment: I personally find the incorrect indenting that Eclipse applies to my lines to be distracting.  Because I'm nitpicky I then stop my flow to go and fix it.  This causes me to slow down when I'm working.  This makes me very sad.

Comment: I'm encountering similar issue with more recent Eclipse 4.2. Concerning about indentation as part of code style is actually part of productivity in coding as there might a particular style of code a coder is more familiar to read than others which is indeed very important to me for more effectively overviewing recent code or complex software on coding as well as on bug hunting. (@JesperE) Have you ever tried to continue (after previous suspend) writing an essay in Word using Comics or Brush Script font applied to the whole text by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Eclipse 3.5.2 doesn't have the feature I was asking for. Other answers mention workarounds, but those have some show-stopper side effects.

Answer (score 1):

The Java code formatting options can be found under Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter.  Click the New or Edit button there.  This will allow you to modify the "smart formatting" on almost anything in Java.  This will only apply to your current workspace.  After you have made all your auto-formatting customizations you can "Export" the customization to a file that can be loaded into new workspaces later.

Comment: This has the unwanted show-stopper side effect that it makes Source / Format unindent all class contents. This is not what I want. What I want is automatic indentation instead of smart indentation when I press Enter to start a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit.. (you need to have a non built-in profile which can be changed) -> Identation -> Ident -> Declarations within class body (uncheck)

Comment: This has the unwanted show-stopper side effect that it makes Source / Format unindent all class contents. This is not what I want. What I want is automatic indentation instead of smart indentation when I press Enter to start a new line.